# How to make c program modular with files.h in Codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks, modular

i hope you really can help me.
When i try to divide my c program into files.h i run into this error: undefined reference to value (name of the example function i'm using) in the main.c.

[image: error in main.c]

As you can see from the images when i try to compile functions.c it gives me the error: undefined reference to WinMain. Right now i'm using codeblocks but i get the same error on VS Code.

[image: functions.c]

I read lot of stuff about making new project with Codeblocks but it doesn't work.
Here's my functions.h:

[image: functions.h]

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: you must also link the ```functions.c``` after compiling it separately with the main program while building.

Comment: How i have to link the functions.c? I already said that it doen't allow to compile the .c file cause it says "undefined reference to Main".

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have two issues preventing `value()` from being found, either:

1. You have not included `functions.c` as a file to be linked, or
2. You have not included `functions.h` in your include search path.

The easiest way to make sure that `functions.c` will be linked as part of the project, is to Right-Click on the file and choose *Properties..* and confirm it is one of the files to be linked:

[image]

To ensure your header has been included as part of the project and in the search path, from the Menu *Project -> Properties...* and check the *Build Target Files* (bottom part of dialog), e.g.

[image]

With `function.c`, and your `provamodulare.c` set to be linked (1) and `functions.h` as part of the build target files, you can build the project just by choosing build.

**Note**

If you plan on using the update value of `x` back in your main file (e.g. in your `provamodulare.c`), you need to pass a pointer (e.g. pass the address of `x`) so that the value at that memory address can be updated in `value()` and the change be visible back in the calling function, e.g.

```
void value (int *x)
{
    *x += 1;
    printf ("%d\n", *x);
}
```

and then in the caller, you would do:

```
    value (&x);
```

after which you could output the updated value in the caller, e.g.

```
    printf ("updated value in caller: %d\n", x);
```

Double check your settings in Code::Blocks as shown above and try again and let me know if you have further problems.

Answer (score 0):

In `functions.c` you have used `printf`, however not included its declaration. Add `stdio.h` header in this file too.

And also see [this wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ) and [user manual working with projects section](https://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html) to troubleshoot the build issues you are facing.